# SQL CASE adds extra column

Tags: sql, oracle, null, case

I am trying to use CASE operator (in Oracle) for NULL replacement:

```
SELECT 
 orderID, 
 shippedDate,
CASE WHEN shippedDate IS NULL 
 THEN 'Not Shipped' 
 END 
FROM ORDERS
WHERE SHIPPEDDATE is NULL;
```

But for some reason it adds an extra column with my replacement value, instead of replacing SHIPPEDDATE null-value:

[image: extra column]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're displaying 3 values in select statement, that is why you're receiving such output. Display only the order_id and the case_value.

Use this query:

```
SELECT 
 orderID, 
CASE 
  WHEN shippedDate IS NULL THEN 'Not Shipped'
  END 
 AS shippedFinalDate
FROM ORDERS
WHERE SHIPPEDDATE is NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to exclude the actual ShippedDate column. If you don't want it, then don't include it. It's not required in order for the CASE statement to work.

```
SELECT 
  orderID, 
  CASE WHEN shippedDate IS NULL 
   THEN 'Not Shipped'
   ELSE 'Shipped'
  END 
FROM ORDERS
WHERE SHIPPEDDATE is NULL;
```

Comment: @MichaelBobryashov no problem. Please remember to mark the best answer as accepted, thankyou.